# How to get a value into an XML tag in SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I don't know how to get a value into an XML tag, in SQL.
For example, my XML is:

```
<myXML>
  <tag Id="Color" Value="Blue"> Some text </tag>
  <tag Id="Color" Value="Red"> Some text2 </tag>
</myXML>
```

I know how to put in a table both lines.
I know how to get values "Some text" and "Some text 2".
But I don't know how to get "Red" and "Blue" and found nothing to explain how...

Comment: Consider adding more info to the question, currently it's very hard for anyone to answer. What database are you using, what have you tried to so far, why didn't it work etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that your tags are *key-value-pairs* where `Id="Color"` is the *key*, while `Value="Blue"` is the value.

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @XML XML= 
'<myXML>
    <tag Id="Color" Value="Blue">Some text</tag>
    <tag Id="Color" Value="Red">Some text2</tag>
    <tag Id="Shape" Value="Rectangle"> Some text3 </tag>
    <tag Id="Width" Value="100">Data-type INT</tag>
</myXML>';
```

--This statement will return a classical *key-value-pairs*-list

```
SELECT tag.value('@Id', 'varchar(max)') AS [Key]
      ,tag.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') AS [Value]
      ,tag.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') TheContent
FROM @XML.nodes('/myXML/tag') AS A(tag);
```

--And this will return each value in a dedicated column (which allows typing)

```
SELECT tag.value('.[@Id="Color"]/@Value', 'varchar(max)') AS Color
      ,tag.value('.[@Id="Shape"]/@Value', 'varchar(max)') AS Shape
      ,tag.value('.[@Id="Width"]/@Value', 'int') AS Width --typed as INT
      ,tag.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') TheContent
FROM @XML.nodes('/myXML/tag') AS A(tag);
```

Comment: thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm a begginer sorry ! It's okay now.

Comment: @KyaaQx Thank, Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this option-

```
DECLARE @DXML XML= 
'<myXML>
    <tag Id="Color" Value="Blue"> Some text </tag>
    <tag Id="Color" Value="Red"> Some text2 </tag>
</myXML>';


SELECT 
T.N.value('@Value', 'varchar(MAX)') AS Color
FROM @dxml.nodes('/myXML/tag') AS T(N)
```

Output is-

```
Color
Blue
Red
```

Comment: I assume, that it is not enough to read the `@Value` and call it `AS Color`... The `Id` attribute seems to point to a *key-value-pair* structure... You might want to read my answer...

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: You are most welcome :)